# Finding unique values of a a grouped column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a columns in df such as below:

```
Site      | Segment
espn.com    groupa
news.com    groupa
cnn.com     groupb
dc.com      groupc
espn.com    groupb
continued...
```

If I want to find unique sites that only exist in a segment how can I get that?

Meaning I only want to find unique websites that exist in one segment but not in any other.

So if cnn.com only exists in group b than I want that and not espn.com

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) for reshape and then found index values if only one value is non missing per rows:

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index='Site', columns='Segment', aggfunc='size')
print (df1)
Segment   groupa  groupb  groupc
Site                            
cnn.com      NaN     1.0     NaN
dc.com       NaN     NaN     1.0
espn.com     1.0     1.0     NaN
news.com     1.0     NaN     NaN

print (df1.notna().sum(axis=1))
Site
cnn.com     1
dc.com      1
espn.com    2
news.com    1
dtype: int64

a = df1.index[df1.notna().sum(axis=1).eq(1)].tolist()
print (a)
['cnn.com', 'dc.com', 'news.com']
```